# Generating random words by grammar

Tags: algorithm-analysis, formal-grammars, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms

### A bit of context

I was writing a parser for a grammar, and for testing purposes I come up with idea to generate some random inputs. The grammar I was dealing with was much more complicated, in this question I presented "minimal working example" for simplicity. And of course, I am able to avoid the issue I faced using a bunch of trivial heuristics, but the question really makes me wonder.

### The problem

Suppose we have a typical context-free grammar for arithmetic expressions of $+,*$, brackets, and integer literals:

$$E \longrightarrow F(“+”F)^*$$
$$F \longrightarrow T(“*”T)^*$$
$$T \longrightarrow int|“(”E“)”$$

It is easy to implement a staighforward algorithm for generating random words by this grammar: we implement a separate procedure for each nonterminal. If a nonterminal has multiple production rules (as $T$ does), we choose a production rule by tossing a coin. If rule contains kleene star (e.g. $(“+”F)^*$), we also toss a coin and generate zero or one repetition (sure we could pick any random integer $k\geq0$ and generate $k$ repetitions, but for simplicity we will focus on the simplest version of this procedure). Here is what we get:

```
generate_E():
    if coin_toss():
        return generate_F() + "+" + generate_F()
    else:
        return generate_F()

generate_F():
    if coin_toss():
        return generate_T() + "*" + generate_T()
    else:
        return generate_F()

def generate_T():
    if coin_toss():
        return "(" + generate_E() + ")"
    else:
        return random_integer()
```

An invocation of generate_E() yields a random expression.

What could go wrong? It turns out that execution of this procedure on the real machine terminates with stack overflow quite often. Of course, technically here we have a possibility of endless recursion, but my intuition was telling me that probability of reaching recursion depth $k$ decays exponentially with increasing $k$, therefore getting deep levels (let's say, 1000) is almost impossible. Apparently, a few consecutive runs reveals that procedure can easily reach depth of many thousands (by depth I mean maximum number of procedure calls the stack contains simultaneously).

I am curios how to formalize this empirical fact. I want either a formula for $P(depth = k)$, or an asymptotic approximation of it, or an inequality bounding right tail of CDF below (something like $P(depth > 1000) > 0.05$)

### My attempt

I tried to come up with a formula for $P(depth = k)$:

Let's denote $P(depth = k)$ as $P_E(k)$. Also, we define similar values for *generate_F()* and *generate_T()* - $P_F(k)$ and $P_T(k)$ respectivetely.

Clearly (*else* branch of *generate_T*), $$P_T(1) = \frac{1}{2}$$ and for $k > 1$ (*then* branch)$$P_T(k) = \frac{1}{2}P_E(k - 1)$$

Regarding $P_F(k)$, we can either execute *else* branch, and it gives term $$\frac{1}{2}P_T(k - 1)$$, or *then* branch, what gives a bit more complicated one $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{(x, y) | max(x, y) = k - 1}{P_T(x)P_T(y)}$$ i.e. $$P_F(k)= \frac{1}{2}(P_F(k - 1) + \sum_{(x, y) | max(x, y) = k - 1}{P_T(x)P_T(y)})$$

Finally, the formula for $P_E(k)$ is almost the same as for $P_F(f)$, we only have to replace $P_T(x)$ with $P_F(x)$.

Now, we can calculate some values of $P_e(k)$

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline k & P_E(k) & P_E(k)\text{ in decimal}& P_E(k)\text{ by Monte-Carlo} \\ \hline 3 & \frac{33}{128} & \approx0.257812 & \approx0.2527 \\ \hline 6 & \frac{4448787585}{34359738368} & \approx0.129477 & \approx0.1282 \\ \hline 9 & \frac{14080391757747154038821618051813151497122305}{178405961588244985132285746181186892047843328} & \approx0.078923 & \approx0.0761 \\ \hline 12 & \text{ the fraction is too long} & \approx0.053213 & \approx0.0530 \\ \hline  \end{array}

As we can see, the recurrent formulas seem to be true, but neither they give me an insight on asymptotical behaviour of $P_E(k)$, nor the first values give a clue on formula in closed form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What a topical question for these days!

Comment: This is a common problem when using random testing tools like QuickCheck to generate recursive data structures. My preferred solution is to add a "fuel" parameter to each procedure, and divide it up randomly amonst calls to other generators; e.g. to make a list of `F` we can pick a number $n \in [0,fuel)$, use $n$ fuel to generate the first `F` and $fuel - n$ fuel to generate the rest of the list (stopping at 0 fuel). Using a fixed stopping probability tends to only generate wide, shallow examples; using fuel allows deep, narrow results too (for the same memory usage)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your process is a textbook example of a [branching process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process). Starting with one $E$, we have an expected $3/2$ many $F$s, $9/4$ many $T$s, and so $9/8$ many remaining $E$s in expectation. Since $9/8 > 1$, it is not surprising that your process often failed to terminate.

To gain more information, we need to know the exact distribution of the number of $E$-offsprings, which is given by the following generating function (see the Wikipedia article linked to above):
$$
h(z) = \frac{33}{128} + \frac{7}{16}z+ \frac{15}{64}z^2 + \frac{1}{16}z^3 + \frac{1}{128}z^4.
$$
This implies that the extinction probability is $d \approx 0.717778143742483$ (by solving $h(z) = z$). This is an upper bound on the probability that your procedure terminates.

We can easily recover your numbers by considering iterates of $h$. The probability that the process terminates in $3k$ steps is $h^{(k)}(0)$. So computing $h(0),h(h(0))-h(0),h(h(h(0)))-h(h(0))$ and so on, we recover the figures in your table.

When $k$ is large, $h^{(k)}(0) \approx d$. We can compute $h'(d) \approx 0.882115879977412$. We have
$$
\frac{d - h^{(k)}(0)}{d - h^{(k-1)}(0)} =
\frac{h(d) - h(h^{(k-1)}(0))}{d - h^{(k-1)}(0)} \approx h'(d).
$$
It follows that
$$
d - h^{(k)}(0) \propto h'(d)^k.
$$
Therefore the probability that the process terminates in exactly $3k$ steps is
$$
h^{(k)}(0) - h^{(k-1)}(0) =
[d - h^{(k-1)}(0)] - [d - h^{(k)}(0)] \propto h'(d)^{k-1} - h'(d)^k \propto h'(d)^k.
$$
Empirically, we can check that the constant of proportionality is roughly $0.0248011196615094$.

Comment: Many thanks for the great explanation and references!

Answer (score 7):

As Yuval has noted, this way of randomly generating recursive data structures is known to (usually) end up with an infinite expected size.

There is, however, a solution to the problem, that allows one to weigh the recursive choices in such a way that expected size lies within a certain finite interval: [Boltzmann samplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_sampler).  They are based on the combinatorial generating function of the structure and come from combinatorial species theory.  For practical implementations, you don't need the theoretical parts, though.  A good programmatic introduction in Haskell can be found [in Brent Yorgey's blog](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/random-binary-trees-with-a-size-limited-critical-boltzmann-sampler-2/).  If you can read (or decipher) Haskell, porting the approach to your own data structure isn't too difficult.

As an example for how a derivation like yours looks within that framework, read [Counting and generating terms in the binary lambda calculus](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/52298129.pdf) by Grygiel & Lescanne (spoiler: it's a surprising amount of complex analysis).